# IBM Websphere - deploy Application to a remote server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I successfully deployed war file and wlapp, adapters  via server configuration tool and worklight console respectively, I am not able to communicate with the remote server. But from development environment, i am able to communicate with the app server.

Help me someone who have ideas and knowledge on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify, in what way are you not able to communicate with the remote server? When trying to access the application as a user? if so how are you trying to access it?

Comment: I have a development environment with a local worklight server, application server and Database in my machine.I have certain users for the application. I can login using an existing username and password from a device and from worklight console. I  moved the application server,DB and  Worklight server (Liberty Profile) to an independent machine.I deployed war file via server config tool. Application & adapter via console. Now I am not able to login as a user even from the worklight console.

Comment: Not helpful. Logs? error messages?

Comment: Websphere allows to deploy the application as well as the wlapps and adapters,there is not any error messages other than the client gives, as "Login Communication Failure". This is the error message passed from client application to the user while the application server can't be reached.

Comment: Sounds like you are not building the app correctly; you need to choose run as > build for remote server and make sure you are using the correct server values (the way to do this will change depending on your worklight version, which you also failed to mention).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, after deploying the .adapter and .wlapp to the remote, your app is unable to connect to the remote server.

To me then it sounds like you are not building the app correctly for the remote server. You need to right-click on the application folder and select Run As > Build Settings and Deploy Target, and make sure you are using the correct server values for the remote server. You then need to deploy the .war to the remote application server and when done with that - deploy the .adapter and .wlapp files.

When trying to connect from the newly generated app, it should successfully connect - to the remote server.